# Puppeteer Issue : Empty form triggered after completed by Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Iam new to puppeteer and iam trying to fill this form with puppeteer, and after fixing issues with selectors, Iam using `page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('... input[value=...]').click())` instead of `page.click('')`
But now iam running into an other issue, when i click on the "Calculate" Button, a form error triggers as if some fields were empty ! 
Here is my entire code :

```
    // const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, slowMo: 50 });
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, slowMo: 50 });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://www.eatthismuch.com/');


    var data = {
        age: '22',
        weight: '80',
        height: '180',
        intention: 'Prendre du poids',
        sexe: 'Femme',
        fat: 'Moyen (de 14% a 22%)',
        activity: 'Extremement actif',
        nb_repas: '3',
        diet: "Pas de restrictions particulières"
    }
    //Menu Vege
    await page.click('#main_container > div > div.home_generator_box.container > div.row.generator_header_div > div.generator_header.col-12.col-md-10.offset-md-1.col-lg-8.offset-lg-2 > div.preset_selector_div > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a')

    //Iam not sure
    page.click('#not_sure_button')
    await page.waitForTimeout(2000)

    //Intention
    switch (data.intention) {
        case 'Perdre du poids':
            await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(`#goal-radio input[value=L]`).click())
            break
        case 'Prendre du poids':
            await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(`#goal-radio input[value=G]`).click())
            break
        default:
            await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(`#goal-radio input[value=M]`).click())

            break
    }

    //Pref units 
    await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(`#units-radio input[value=M]`).click())

    //Male/Female
    switch (data.sexe) {
        case 'Homme':
            await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(`#gender-radio input[value=M]`).click())
            break
        case 'Femme':
            await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(`#gender-radio input[value=F]`).click())
            break
        default:
            await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(`#gender-radio input[value=M]`).click())

            break
    }

    //Values
    await page.$eval('#height-secondary', el => el.value = '180');
    await page.$eval('#weight', el => el.value = '70');
    await page.$eval('#age', el => el.value = '22');

    //BodyFat
    switch (data.fat) {
        case 'Bas (moins de 14%)':
            await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(`#bodyfat-radio input[value='10']`).click())
            break
        case 'Haut (plus de 22%)':
            await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(`#bodyfat-radio input[value='30']`).click())
            break
        default:
            //Moyen (de 14% a 22%)
            await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(`#bodyfat-radio input[value='20']`).click())

            break
    }


    //Activity
    switch (data.activity) {
        case 'Peu actif':
            await page.select('select[name="activity_level"]', '1.375')
            break
        case 'Moyennement actif':
            await page.select('select[name="activity_level"]', '1.55')

            break
        case 'Très actif':
            await page.select('select[name="activity_level"]', '1.725')

            break
        case 'Extremement actif':
            await page.select('select[name="activity_level"]', '1.9')

            break
        default:
            //Sedentaire
            await page.select('select[name="activity_level"]', '1.2')

            break
    }
    //Calcul
    await page.waitForTimeout(4000)
    await page.click('#calculate_button')

    const calories = await page.$eval('#nutrition_calculator_view > div > div > div.modal-body > div.macro_recommendation > table > tbody > tr > td.suggested_calories', el => el.innerText);

    console.log(calories);



    // await browser.close();

    // return calories
})()
```

I tried to put 2 `waitForTimeout()` to see if it could resolved it but it doesn't seems to come from timing ! 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6ps7.png

Comment: Welcome to SO! Just a software engineering suggestion: use objects instead of switch statements everywhere. The switch statements lead to very WET (wrote everything twice, or in this case 3-5 times) code. You can DRY it out by creating objects like `intentions = {'Perdre du poids': 'L', ...}`, then using them with `intentions[data.intention] || defaultVal` to grab the right value and pass it to your evaluate calls. These "config" objects can be essentially JSON and loaded from an external file, making the program much cleaner and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to click on labels, not on inputs for the form check being valid. I.e. instead of:

```js
await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(`#goal-radio input[value=L]`).click())
```

you need

```js
await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(`#goal-radio label[for="c56_goal-0"]`).click())
```

This seems working for me:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, slowMo: 50 });
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto('https://www.eatthismuch.com/');

var data = {
    age: '22',
    weight: '80',
    height: '180',
    intention: 'Prendre du poids',
    sexe: 'Femme',
    fat: 'Moyen (de 14% a 22%)',
    activity: 'Extremement actif',
    nb_repas: '3',
    diet: "Pas de restrictions particulières"
}
//Menu Vege
await page.click('#main_container > div > div.home_generator_box.container > div.row.generator_header_div > div.generator_header.col-12.col-md-10.offset-md-1.col-lg-8.offset-lg-2 > div.preset_selector_div > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a')

//Iam not sure
page.click('#not_sure_button')
await page.waitForTimeout(2000)

//Intention
switch (data.intention) {
    case 'Perdre du poids':
        await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(`#goal-radio label[for="c56_goal-0"]`).click())
        break
    case 'Prendre du poids':
        await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(`#goal-radio label[for="c56_goal-2"]`).click())
        break
    default:
        await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(`#goal-radio label[for="c56_goal-1"]`).click())

        break
}

//Pref units
await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(`#units-radio label[for="c56_units-1"]`).click())

//Male/Female
switch (data.sexe) {
    case 'Homme':
        await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(`#gender-radio label[for="c56_gender-0"]`).click())
        break
    case 'Femme':
        await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(`#gender-radio label[for="c56_gender-1"]`).click())
        break
    default:
        await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(`#gender-radio label[for="c56_gender-0"]`).click())

        break
}

//Values
await page.$eval('#height-secondary', el => el.value = '180');
await page.$eval('#weight', el => el.value = '70');
await page.$eval('#age', el => el.value = '22');

//BodyFat
switch (data.fat) {
    case 'Bas (moins de 14%)':
        await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(`#bodyfat-radio label[for="c56_bodyfat-0"]`).click())
        break
    case 'Haut (plus de 22%)':
        await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(`#bodyfat-radio label[for="c56_bodyfat-1"]`).click())
        break
    default:
        //Moyen (de 14% a 22%)
        await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(`#bodyfat-radio label[for="c56_bodyfat-2"]`).click())

        break
}

//Activity
switch (data.activity) {
    case 'Peu actif':
        await page.select('select[name="activity_level"]', '1.375')
        break
    case 'Moyennement actif':
        await page.select('select[name="activity_level"]', '1.55')

        break
    case 'Très actif':
        await page.select('select[name="activity_level"]', '1.725')

        break
    case 'Extremement actif':
        await page.select('select[name="activity_level"]', '1.9')

        break
    default:
        //Sedentaire
        await page.select('select[name="activity_level"]', '1.2')

        break
}
//Calcul
await page.waitForTimeout(4000)
await page.click('#calculate_button')

const calories = await page.$eval('#nutrition_calculator_view > div > div > div.modal-body > div.macro_recommendation > table > tbody > tr > td.suggested_calories', el => el.innerText);

console.log(calories);
```